# DocuSign JWT Auth Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate DocuSign in my web application (.net framework 4.8). I'm using DocuSign eSign dll version 6.5.0.

I am trying to get an access token using JWT auth grant. I created an App and Integration Key in the DocuSign developer portal, and have granted consent.

However, when I attempt to get an Access token, it throws an ApiException with message:
**Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body:**

```
    getAuthInfo(out string clientID, out string rsaPrivateKey, out string impersonatedUserID);

    var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient();

    var scopes = new List<string>{"signature","impersonation"};

    var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rsaPrivateKey);

    try
    {
        var authToken = docuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                            clientID,
                            impersonatedUserID,
                            "account-d.docusign.com",
                            privateKeyBytes,
                            1,
                            scopes);
                            
        return authToken;               
    }
    catch (ApiException apiExp)
    {
        // Consent for impersonation must be obtained to use JWT Grant
        if (apiExp.Message.Contains("consent_required"))
        {
            
        }
    }
```

*** **Update**: ***

Installed eSign dll version 6.2.0 to match the same version as the Quick Start Console version which I confirmed works.

Also, changed the DocuSignClient instnatiation to pass a config with dev URL.

```
    getAuthInfo(out string clientID, out string rsaPrivateKey, out string impersonatedUserID);

    var config = new DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
    var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(config);

    var scopes = new List<string>{"signature","impersonation"};

    var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rsaPrivateKey);

    try
    {
        var authToken = docuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                            clientID,
                            impersonatedUserID,
                            "account-d.docusign.com",
                            privateKeyBytes,
                            1,
                            scopes);
                            
        return authToken;               
    }
    catch (ApiException apiExp)
    {
        // Exception Message: "Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body: "
    }
```

*** **Update 2**: ***

```
    string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
    string fileName = "private.key";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
    var privateKeyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    try
    {
        var accessToken = JWTAuth.AuthenticateWithJWT("ESignature", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatedUserID"],
                                                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"], privateKeyBytes);
    }
    catch (DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException apiExp)
    {
        // Exception: Error code 500
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Not sure what version of TLS the eSign dll uses, but explicitly setting the SecurityProtocol to use Tls12 fixed my issue.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var authToken = docuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                                clientID,
                                impersonatedUserID,
                                url,
                                privateKeyBytes,
                                1,
                                scopes);
```

Comment: While this may work for a good chunk of time, you should be careful of hardcoding version 1.2 because version 1.3 is more secure and eventually will be the default. I would check to see why this was even needed. This is not set by the DocuSign DLL, this may be set by your code, or server, or something else you have going.

Comment: Our server blocks versions of TLS older than 1.1. Perhaps the Nuget package was trying to use a TLS other than 1.2 that we were blocking? Once I set it to 1.2, it started working. Not sure when would be a good time to change to 1.3...wouldn't seem wise to wait until we start getting exceptions when 1.3 becomes the default. But also not able to debug the code used by the Nuget package to see what version it's trying to use by default.

Answer (score 0):

Save the RSA private key into a text file called private.key

Then do this :

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("private.key");
var authToken = docuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
                            clientID,
                            impersonatedUserID,
                            "account-d.docusign.com",
                            privateKeyBytes,
                            1,
                            scopes);
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way? The rsa key is stored in our DB and retrieved as a string.

Comment: This did not help. I've also downloaded the C# Quick Start Console App Demo, which seems to be working fine. I set a breakpoint when calling RequestJWTUserToken and swapped out the clientID and privateKeyBytes with the ones I'm using from my Web App and it seems to be working fine there as it returns an Access token. The console app is using eSign dll version 6.2.0 whereas  my Web App is using 6.5.0. Other than that I'm not seeing much of a difference.

Comment: This cannot be the only difference. You can confirm by changing your web app to 6.2.0 and see if it helps

Comment: I still believe the issue is the way you retrieve the bytes of the RSA key. Can you make sure it's done in the same identical way that the quickstart does it?

Comment: BTW, you can also download the 3rd optino for C# quickstart which is a web app that does both JWT and ACG. You can see how JWT is done in a web app (Which is essentially the same, but just in case)

Comment: Thank you Inbar. I tried File.ReadAllBytes("private.key") but am getting the same error message. The error message status code is 500. See updated post above.

Comment: Inbar, my Web application is a .Net Framework 4.8 WebForms application. Is there something in my settings in maybe web.config that may be blocking this call? I created a new WebForms project (empty), and everything seems to be working fine there. I copied/pasted all the code. So I'm sure the code is not the issue, but maybe a configuration in IIS or web.config?

Comment: Did you try the web quickstart?

Comment: IIS is not involved, you're making HTTP calls outbound

Comment: When you get the 500 error, is there any other information in the exception message that you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [src code](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-csharp-client/blob/8639d01700d5f6606e95b2a744e2796b085867a0/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/DocuSignClient.cs#L91) it appears that the sdk oauth server default is now production.

Fix is to explicitly create a "configuration" object with the demo oauth url for your DocuSignClient constructor

Comment: Thank you Larry. Please see my updated post. Tried it this way and still not working for me. The exception error message does not contain a Body so it makes it very difficult to troubleshoot.